# {message: "Auth failed", success: false} message : "Auth failed" success : false

Tags: express, asynchronous, authorization, mern

I'm following a Udemy MERN stack course and I am quite a beginner ,I've got stuck in middle of a problem. There is no point in completing it before solving this problem. The problem is with the concept of authorization and concept of protected roles, so when the user is logged in to the interface we have to check whether is user is authorized or not. I followed the instructer end to end exactly according to the instruction and his code.

Using jsonwebtoken, verifiationn is conducted on the basis of encrypted token. whos key is stored in .env file

The output of the network dev tool in the browser :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ARQk2.png)

I have no idea what causes this.

**server.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
require("dotenv").config();
const dbConfig = require("./config/dbConfig.js");
app.use(express.json());
const userRoute = require("./routes/userRoute");

app.use("/api/user", userRoute);
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

console.log(process.env.MONGO_URL);
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Node server started at port ${port}`));
```

**.env**

```
MONGO_URL = 'mongodb+srv://users:root@cluster0.vnoq4f8.mongodb.net/ngodatabase';
JWT_SECRET = 'ngo_project';
```

**Home.js**

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
function Home() {
  const getData = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.post(
        "/api/user/get-user-info-by-id",
        {},
        {
          headers: {
            Authorization: "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("token"),
          }, // headers
        }
      );
      console.log(response.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, []);
  return <div>Home</div>;
}

export default Home;
```

**authmiddleware.js**

```
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
module.exports = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const token = req.headers["authorization"].split(" ")[1];
    jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET, (err, decoded) => {
      if (err) {
        return res.status(401).send({
          message: "Auth failed",
          success: false,
        });
      } else {
        req.body.userId = decoded.id;
        next();
      }
    });
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(401).send({
      message: "Auth failed",
      success: false,
    });
  }
};
```

**userRoute.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const User = require("../models/userModel");
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const authmiddleware = require("../middlewares/authmiddleware");

router.post("/register", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const userExist = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email });
    if (userExist) {
      return res
        .status(200)
        .send({ message: "User already exists", success: false });
    }
    const password = req.body.password;
    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt);
    req.body.password = hashedPassword;
    const newuser = new User(req.body);
    await newuser.save();
    res
      .status(200)
      .send({ message: "User created successfully", success: true });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res
      .status(500)
      .send({ message: "Error creating user", success: false, error });
  }
});

router.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const user = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email });
    if (!user) {
      return res
        .status(200)
        .send({ message: "User does not exist", success: false });
    }
    const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password);
    if (!isMatch) {
      return res
        .status(200)
        .send({ message: "Password is incorrect", success: false });
    } else {
      const token = jwt.sign({ id: user._id }, process.env.JWT_SECRET, {
        expiresIn: "1d",
      });
      res
        .status(200)
        .send({ message: "login successful", success: true, data: token });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res
      .status(500)
      .send({ message: "Error logging in", success: false, error });
  }
});

router.post("/get-user-info-by-id", authmiddleware, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const user = await User.findOne({ _id: req.body.userId });
    if (!user) {
      return res
        .status(200)
        .send({ message: "User does not exist", success: false });
    } else {
      res.status(200).send({
        success: true,
        data: {
          name: user.name,
          email: user.email,
        },
      });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).send({
      message: "Error getting user information",
      success: false,
      error,
    });
  }
});
module.exports = router;
```

**package.json**
[jsonwebtoken in package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N42kN.png)

**Login.js**

```
import { Button, Form, Input } from "antd";
import React from "react";
import toast from "react-hot-toast";
import { Link, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";

function Login() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const onFinish = async (values) => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.post("/api/user/login", values);
      if (response.data.success) {
        toast.success(response.data.message);
        toast("Redirecting to home page");
        localStorage.setItem("token", response.data.data);
        navigate("/");
      } else {
        toast.error(response.data.message);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      toast.error("Something went wrong");
    }
  };
  return (
    <div className="authentication">
      <div className="authentication-form card p-4">
        <h1 className="card-title">Welcome Back</h1>
        <Form layout="vertical" onFinish={onFinish}>
          <Form.Item label="Email" name="email">
            <Input placeholder="Email"></Input>
          </Form.Item>
          <Form.Item label="Password" name="password">
            <Input placeholder="Password" type="password"></Input>
          </Form.Item>
          <Button className="primary-button my-2" htmlType="submit">
            LOGIN
          </Button>
          <Link to="/register" className="anchor mt-2">
            CLICK HERE TO REGISTER
          </Link>
        </Form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Login;
```

**Register.js**

```
import { Button, Form, Input } from "antd";
import React from "react";
import { Link, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";
import toast from "react-hot-toast";

function Register() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const onFinish = async (values) => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.post("/api/user/register", values);
      if (response.data.success) {
        toast.success(response.data.message);
        toast("Redirecting to login page");
        navigate("/login");
      } else {
        toast.error(response.data.message);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      toast.error("Something went wrong");
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="authentication">
      <div className="authentication-form card p-4">
        <h1 className="card-title">Nice to meet you</h1>
        <Form layout="vertical" onFinish={onFinish}>
          <Form.Item label="Name" name="name">
            <Input type="text" placeholder="Name" name="name"></Input>
          </Form.Item>
          <Form.Item label="Email" name="email">
            <Input type="email" placeholder="Email" name="email"></Input>
          </Form.Item>
          <Form.Item label="Password" name="password">
            <Input
              placeholder="Password"
              name="password"
              type="password"
            ></Input>
          </Form.Item>
          <Button
            className="primary-button my-2"
            htmlType="submit"
            name="submit"
          >
            REGISTER
          </Button>
          <Link to="/Login" className="anchor mt-2">
            CLICK HERE TO LOGIN
          </Link>
        </Form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Register;
```

Answer (score 0):

did you check if you already have the token in your storage ?

check using inspectElement, or try to print the token in **authmiddleware.js**

like:

```
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
module.exports = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const token = req.headers["authorization"].split(" ")[1];
    jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET, (err, decoded) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(token); //this line will print the token that given in your request
        return res.status(401).send({
          message: "Auth failed",
          success: false,
        });
      } else {
        req.body.userId = decoded.id;
        next();
      }
    });
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(401).send({
      message: "Auth failed",
      success: false,
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: I can see the token in the application section in browser but the console is showing such type of error -- AxiosError {message: 'Request failed with status code 401', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}
code

"ERR_BAD_REQUEST"   config
adapter
(2) ['xhr', 'http']
data
"{}"
env
Blob
ƒ Blob()
FormData ƒ FormData()
[[Prototype]]
: 
Object
headers

Comment: @Code Screenshot :  (https://i.stack.imgur.com/9g7xD.png)

Comment: Actually just like you said , by performing console.log(token); , i can see the output of token in the backend side in nodeman server (https://i.stack.imgur.com/qMPSR.png)